# Cannot read property 'createTransport' of undefined

Tags: javascript, email, meteor, nodemailer

I am testing sending email with meteor js and nodemailer plugin:

meteor add mrt:meteor-nodemailer

when the page loaded, i saw error in the console of the navigator :
Cannot read property 'createTransport' of undefined.

so what is the problem ?

this is the code :

///////////////////////////////////////////

```
var nodemailer = Nodemailer;

var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        user: "myname@gmail.com",
        pass: "mypass"
    }
});

var emailNodemailer = function() {

    // setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
    var mailOptions = {
        from: "Sender Name ✔ ", // sender address
        to: "someone@yahoo.fr", // list of receivers
        subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
        text: "Hello world ✔", // plaintext body
        html: "Hello world ✔" // html body
    };

    // send mail with defined transport object
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
        if(error){
           console.log(error);
        }else{
           console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
        }

        // if you don't want to use this transport object anymore, uncomment following line
        //smtpTransport.close(); // shut down the connection pool, no more messages
    });

};
```

///////////////

Comment: Did you make any progress with this one? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Dear @user3385657,
Could you please check whether you have imported nodemailer using require like below?
`var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');`

Comment: have same issue, smth is broken

Answer (score 27):

This worked for me `import * as nodemailer from 'nodemailer';`